# Express route does not match without wildcard

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express 3. I have a `GET` route in my code which does not match if I do not place a `*` wildcard at the end

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();

app.get('/image/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send("ok");
});

var port = 3002;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Image Get Server started on port " + port);
```

The code is as above. The URL that I am trying to hit is 
`http://localhost:3002/image/upload/imageId.jpg`

The response that I get is `Cannot GET /image/upload/imageId.jpg`

However when I place a wildcard at the end of the route to match

```
app.get('/image/upload*', function(req, res) {
```

it works. I remember the routes working without such wildcards. What is it that I am missing in this?

Comment: and why is this wildcard bothering you if anyway you want to have access to all files?

Comment: `app.get('/image/upload/:filename'`...

Comment: @PawełSmołka Because I love to know why a certain thing works or why it doesn't.

Comment: @brianreavis Thus would not work if I have more "/" in the URL after upload. I will only get upto the first "/" in req.params.filename

Comment: The actual thing I was wondering was if I can use regex in patterns and still use optional spats that match.

Answer (score 1):

you may try:

```
app.get('/image/upload/:name', function (req, res)
    {
        var name = req.params.name;
        try{
            res.send("OK");
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log("Error on: "+name+err);
        }
    });
```

it works at my node, but not sure if it is compatible with express 3